# semantic web request result difference

Tags: sparql, semantics, dbpedia

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

    SELECT * WHERE {
     ?x foaf:primaryTopic ?n .
     ?x rdf:type ?z .

    FILTER (regex(?x, '^http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama$')).
}
LIMIT 10
```

when i call this request from http://dbpedia.org/snorql, it works. but when i try below

```
SELECT * WHERE {
 ?x foaf:primaryTopic ?n .
 ?x rdf:type ?z .
 ?x owl:activeYearsStartDate ?v .
 FILTER (regex(?x, '^http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama$')).
}
```

it doesn't work. but why?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean ? You get an error message?  You don't get the results that you expect?  What?  I *bet* that you don't get any results, since OWL doesn't define a property  `owl:activeYearsStartDate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect that you meant

> ?x dbpedia-owl:activeYearsStartDate ?v .

rather than

> ?x owl:activeYearsStartDate ?v .

Also, using regex here is more expensive than it needs to be.  You could check whether the string value of a URI is something in particular with

> filter( str(?x) = "…" )

but even that is a lot more work than you need.  If you want ?x to be <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama>, just use it instead of ?x, or bind ?x to it with values:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
 <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama> foaf:primaryTopic ?n .
 <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama> rdf:type ?z .
 <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama> owl:activeYearsStartDate ?v .
}
```

```
SELECT * WHERE {
 values ?x { <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama> }
 ?x foaf:primaryTopic ?n .
 ?x rdf:type ?z .
 ?x owl:activeYearsStartDate ?v .
}
```

That *still* looks suspicious, though.  Are you sure you didn't want <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barack_Obama>?  And the use of foaf:primaryTopic stuff really makes me think that you want something more like:

```
select * {
  ?x foaf:isPrimaryTopicOf <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barack_Obama> ;
     a ?type ;
     dbpedia-owl:activeYearsStartDate ?v
}
limit 10
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20*%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%3Fx%20foaf%3AisPrimaryTopicOf%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FBarack_Obama%3E%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20a%20%3Ftype%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20dbpedia-owl%3AactiveYearsStartDate%20%3Fv%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%2010&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)